# Can a meeple be placed, and scored on the same turn?

Tags: carcassonne

Can I place the completing tile of a free road/city, put a meeple on it, and then score and take that meeple back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is a basic game play rule of Carcassone. A turn has the following steps:

- Draw and place a terrain tile
- Station a follower on the newly-placed tile (optional)
- Score completed feature(s) (if relevant)

Since you place a meeple before scoring, you can place one down, count the points and take it back. You can only place one down though if no other meeple is already on the connected part.

Comment: That's exactly how I thought it works, but wanted to check twice. Thanks a lot.